# How can I embed a QSlider in my QML application instead of it popping up as a separate window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to embed one QSlider in a qml application but the Qslider is popping up as separate window

I tried of creating Qslider inside the function and if use show() function its poping up as an different window but my need is to embed the Qslider in my qml application itself .

Comment: Did you try the QtQuick.Controls Slider component? Within QML you're not supposed to use the C++ QWidget classes; they are largely independent GUI frameworks.